# Changing Android App Overview Name In Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

Some of the android phones displays app name on overview window. Even I change the app name in AndroidManifest.xml (android:label="Mobile®Store") it's not working for the overview name(It writes app_name). Also I search "app_name" word in project and there is no "app_name" word in project. I can't find anything for this problem.

[App on apps window with right name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpWP9.jpg)

[App on overview window with wrong name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp8Df.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This will be defined in your settings as app_name. Or if you are getting settings via Api , then do check for app_name.